# Can I force descendants to have a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am trying to create a generic factory-pattern-like mechanism.

The factory will be like:

```
public class APlugin<ActionType> where ActionType : IAction
{
    // create a new action. Note: ActionType should contain
    // an empty constructor
    public ActionType CreateAction()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<ActionType>();
    }
}
```

Descendants of IAction might hide the parameterless constructor and this will cause the factory to fail.

Comment: Give it the new() constraint so you can just use the constructor, new ActionType().  But not necessarily useful in plug-in scenarios.

Comment: When you say "empty constructor", do you mean a constructor that takes no parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't force an empty constructor or any type of constructor on derived types.

Constructors do not get inherited, but do get called.

If not chaining to the base constructor (using the `: base()` syntax), the default base constructor will be called implicitly.

From [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) on MSDN:

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called explicitly using the base keyword, then the default constructor, if there is one, is called implicitly.

Answer (score 12):

You can ensure class has constructor without arguments by providing generic constraint `where T : new()`. It will affect type `T` only, though. Containing class will be unaffected, so you can make sure `ActionType` in your case has said constructor, but you can't enforce it on any class inheriting from `APlugin<T>`.

Comment: The `new()` generic type constraint simply means that there must be a public parameterless constructor. It does not prevent constructors with parameters to exist to the type constrained (or the derived types).

Comment: I know what `new()` does, but I'm not sure what OP is trying to achieve. It seems he wants to ensure that `Activator.CreateInstance<ActionType>()` won't fail because there are no parameterless constructors. Adding constraint to `ActionType` will take care of that. It won't prevent adding constructors with parameters as long as there is parameterless one as well.

Comment: (cont.) So there might be type implementing from IAction that has no default constructor, but you'll get compiler error when trying to use it as generic type `ActionType` in `APlugin`.

Comment: @Oded sorry about that, I meant what MagnatLU understood. I want somehow to verify that `CreateAction` will not fail.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty late but i think this is worth knowing..

You can force constructors with 0 parameters on non-abstract classes. This is a type constraint to use whenever you want to enforce those constraints on a class structure. It requires you to specify the type that implements the interface which might be found disturbing. That's the price if you want some neat type safety.

```
public interface IEmptyConstructor<TThis> where TThis : IEmptyConstructor<TThis>, new() {}
```

for example a singleton structure

```
public abstract class Singleton<TThis> : ISingleton where TThis : Singleton<TThis>, new() { /* some singleton madness */ }
```